# How to get all the Event Handlers defined for UI control (e.g. TextBox)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mono.cecil

I recently started working with Mono.Cecil library. All I need to know is, all the event handlers defined for a particular UI control (Text Box in this case) in Windows Phone 8 application. I inspected the assembly through ILDASM but could not find any place where event handlers are defined for the control.

Comment: If you're referring to the event handlers defined in the XAML file, you can't find them in the IL. On Windows Phone, the XAML file isn't compiled, it's interpreted at run time

Comment: Thanks KooKiz for the quick response. Yes, I am referring to the event handlers defined in the XAML file. If that is the case then, will it(XAML file) be present in the XAP?

Comment: The XAML file is present in the XAP, but it's embedded as a resource in the assembly (the DLL file). So you can't directly extract the XAML file by unpackaging the XAP.